# Couchbase,Where to add config.json for windows Installation?

Tags: android, json, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to implement Couch base in my android app following the couchbase tutorial link [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/training/build-first-android-app/add-sync-gateway.xml/index.html)

I need to add a config.json file to create my own database link rather than using its default database "Sync_gateway".According to explanation it should be inside bin directory inside a data folder but I can't find a bin directory as I installed sync gatway from .exe file. I don't find run it by any command other than clicking the .exe file. What I am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed sync_gateway in Windows then open the file location for the sync_gateway.exe it will be usually in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Couchbase" . You have to place your **configure.json** in that directory . Now open windows command prompt and do '***cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Couchbase***' and run the command '***sync_gateway.exe configure.json***' . Ensure that your configure.json file is perfect and does not have any syntax errors. your Sync gateway will now load with your specified configure.json