# Couchbase Sync gateway on Windows

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I installed sync_gateway for windows from http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads. 
I am trying to execute command `sync_gateway config.json` but it gives me an error. How to execute config.json to sync data with android device.

My config.json contains

```
{
  "interface":":4984",        
  "adminInterface":":4985",
  "log":["REST"],
  "databases":{              
    "sync_gateway":{
    "server":"http://localhost:8091",
    "bucket":"sync_gateway",
    "sync":`function(doc) {channel(doc.channels);}`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the file location for the `sync_gateway.exe` it will be usually in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Couchbase" .
2. You have to place your configure.json in that directory .
3. Now open windows command prompt and do 'cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Couchbase' and run the command `'sync_gateway.exe configure.json'` . Ensure that your configure.json file is perfect and does not have any syntax errors.

refer [Couchbase,Where to add config.json for windows Installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030843/couchbase-where-to-add-config-json-for-windows-installation) for run config.json

refer [Write config.json for sync_gateway](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check some prerequisites:

1. Sync Gateway is not a product on his own. You must have an available server. (property named "server", with port 8091.
2. You must have bucket named "sync_gateway" in your case
   you can define it with the JSON property above, "bucket"

Roi.